# Bundling fails because path mistaken for a controller path

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

In my BundleConfig I have

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css/css").Include("~/Content/css/wireframe.css?v=1.0"));
```

In my view I have

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css/css")
```

But when I access the page concerned I get a 404 with this error

```
[HttpException]: The controller for path &#39;/Content/css/css&#39; was not found or does not implement IController.
```

It seems the path is being confused for a controller.  Do I change my WebApiConfig and RouteConfig files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Schoolboy error.  I was missing this in the Global.asax

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```