# Css and Js bundling, IController Exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

I am trying to create a bundles of JS and CSS files. The folder structure I have is like this:

> 1. ~
>
>    1. Scripts
>
>       1. A
>       2. B
>       3. C
>    2. Content
>
>       1. CSS
>
>          1. ACSS
>          2. BCSS
>          3. CSS
>       2. IMG

I extracted some help form [MVC Central](http://www.mvccentral.net/Story/Details/articles/kahanu/stylebundle-403-error-solved) and added this code to my project:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/A/AAA").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/A/jquery-{version}.js");
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/B/BBB").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/A/jquery-{version}.js");
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/CSS/ACSS").Include("
                     ~/Content/CSS/ACSS/MyCss-*"));
```

But it'ss returning a 404 exception:

> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The controller for path '/bundles/A/AAA' was not found or does not implement IController.

**Edit:** i have registered my Bundles in `Global.asax` file. so atleast i am not making a schoolboy error.

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

What did I do wrong to cause this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bundling fails because path mistaken for a controller path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195254/bundling-fails-because-path-mistaken-for-a-controller-path)

Comment: No idea why that edit was accepted... has made the question harder to answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster , i am not making that school boy error.

Comment: Well we can't assume anything. Did you try changing `/bundles/` to `/Scripts/`, as that's the folder where your scripts reside and is explained on the page you link to (_"What you need to do is match the bundle name with the actual virtual path to your files!
"_)?

Comment: @CodeCaster yes ! Tried that suggestion Also. but that haven't worked. still giving 404.

Comment: Does the `StyleBundle` work?

Comment: both of them giving me 404. i have Areas in App, with route configuration for landing .Is the custom route can be a problem ?. I modified my bundle to` ~/Content/Scripts/A/AAA`. now its saying `Route not found via RouteConfig`

Comment: I'm getting this same error but intermittently.  I've not seen it on my local dev server but I'm getting about 20 email reports a day from my live server that this has happened.  This happens across different pages.  When I try and replicate the user actions on the live server, the error isn't generated.

Comment: How are you including the bundles on your web pages?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and in the end it appeared that the  System.Web.Optimization.PreApplicationStartCode.Start method was never being called so the paths to the bundles were still being handled by the usual MVC routing.

The fix for me was to manually call it in the Application_Start method of the site's Global.asax.cs file:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //other code startup code here

    System.Web.Optimization.PreApplicationStartCode.Start();
}
```

This way the incoming requests for bundles are handled by the System.Web.Optimization.BundleHandler ProcessRequest method.

For a more detailed look at how the code works under the hood (or *should* do...) it's worth looking here: http://beletsky.net/2012/04/new-in-aspnet-mvc4-bundling-and.html